# Viewing suggested edit inline scrolls page if URL is direct link to comment

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, comments

**How to reproduce:**

1. Have at least 2000 reputation, so you can review suggested edits.
2. Find a question or answer with a pending suggested edit, and a comment on itself, or on a post that appears *later on the same page* (keep in mind that you can sort answers).
3. Click on the comment's date to get a direct link to it.
4. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, to make the page behave as if you followed a link to that comment.
5. Click on `edit(1)` on the question/answer, to view the suggested edit.

**Expected behaviour:**

The "Review Suggested Edit" dialog pops up, and then the page scrolls to position the dialog in the middle of the window.

**Actual behaviour:**

The "Review Suggested Edit" dialog pops up, and then the page scrolls to position **the comment at the top** of the window.

I'm fairly certain this is a bug.

Tested with Chrome 43.0.2357.134.